# 404 errors for pages other than homepage when uploaded to web-server

Tags: 7

I and new to php and I got started with drupal and this is my demo site http://sugandha.net63.net/ Yea and it works but when I try to click on any link it throws 404error message. What might be the problem? It works fine in localhost.

My setting is as follows :

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'a2256974_drupal',
      'username' => 'username',
      'password' => 'pwd',
      'host' => 'mysql1.000webhost.com',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

This is my database setting and

```
 # $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';  // NO trailing slash!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do you have an `.htaccess` file in your root of your installation?

  Its one of the most common problems because its a hidden file and people keep missing uploading it to their web server

if you have the .htaccess file then its got to be your base url..change it like Jorge Córdoba said...

- Uncomment *(remove #)* and change example.com...Like this:

  `# $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';  // NO trailing slash!`

  to

  `$base_url = 'http://sugandha.net63.net';  // NO trailing slash!`

if it still doesn't work:

- try using `?q=` before the relative url..eg:

  `http://sugandha.net63.net/admin` to `http://sugandha.net63.net/?q=admin`

  if that works then you have to disable clean urls on the online installation

Comment: it's not hidden and i uploaded it :)

Comment: if you changed base url and .htaccess is there then i have no clue:P
maybe you should try reinstalling

Comment: and your website is under review so i cant check it online:P
i ll check later once the check is over if i get a clue^^

Comment: yea I don't know it was working :D just recently Is all free webhosting same

Comment: ok,its online and i can see the problem....you dont have clean urls enabled on the web-server...eg http://sugandha.net63.net/node/4 throws 404 but if you go with the normal drupal urls it works...eg `http://sugandha.net63.net/?q=node/4`...you have to disable clean urls from `http://sugandha.net63.net/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls`

Comment: The clean url might be the reason but can't log in through admin :(

Comment: u have to trick drupal:P go here: `http://sugandha.net63.net/?q=user/login` and enter you username/pass.it will throw 404 but you will be logged in if you go to your homepage,after that.then just use the link above to disable clean url

Comment: you are great :D Thanks for advice . Ha Ha Great Trick.

Answer (score 1):

Check the settings for your site, most probably your host string is defined to "localhost" and therefore any links in the site are directed to "localhost/whatever" instead of the actual location.

You need to edit the "$base_url" variable in your settings.php file which can be found in sites/default for single site drupal instalations.

Comment: where can I change the host string

Comment: I was about to post that :)

Comment: Could not get the setting done :( is that because base_url is not configured

Comment: when you put "example.com" ... you do have your actual url there right?

Comment: nope :D I did not change it

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: If it's a new server, make sure that Apache has `mod_rewrite` installed. Happened to me.